# Relationship between symplectic forms and skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-linear-algebra

it is a well-known result that for any skew-symmetric matrix $A$, that is invertible, we have invertible matrices $R$, such that $R^T A R = \left(\begin{array}  00 & Id \\ -Id & 0 \end{array} \right)$. Now since this looks extremely similar to what I know sympletic forms, I was wondering how symplectic forms are related to skew symmetric matrices. Can we even say, that every skew-symmetric matrix that is invertible "creates" a symplectic forms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For every invertible skew symmetric matrix $A$, the bilinear form $(x,y)\mapsto x^t\cdot A\cdot y$ is a symplectic form.

Comment: The converse is also true.